# Convert dict to HTML table

Tags: python

I am new in Python and I wanted to convert below dictionary to html table format in python. Please let me know the efficient way to do achieve this

Input

```
dict_data = {'x,y,z':['1','5','6'],'p,q,r':['10','25','36']}
```

Output :

```
col1     col2 col3 val1 val2

x     y    z    1     5

p     q    r        10    25
```

Comment: Why are there only two value columns listed, while each list contains three elements?

Comment: What framework are you using to output html?  Django or something else?  Or are you just using print statements to output the html to the console?  Or are you using python to write the html to a file?

Comment: I need  first 2 values only.As per my use case it can be first 2 or last 2 or first and last.Basically I need a approach so that I can make it generic

Comment: @kloddant , I just need print statement.Eventually i will redirect the output to Email in html table format

Comment: Are you sure that your dictionary looks like that?
A single string containing "x, y, z" as key?

Comment: @pitto, Yup.It is a single key.

Comment: Hello @tahsinraza!

I've prepared a solution for you.

If you find it useful please remember upvote and/or choose it as answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please test the following script, explanation is available in the comments:

```
dict_data = {'x,y,z':['1','5','6'],'p,q,r':['10','25','36']}

# Here I prepare the html variable I will be updating later
html = '<table style="width:100%">'

# Let's cycle the elements in dict_data
for dict_item in dict_data:
    html += '<tr>'
    # Using split I unpack the values in the key using the , as delimiter
    key_values = dict_item.split(',')
    # Time to fill the table rows with the single key subunits
    html += '<th>' + key_values[0] + '</th>'
    html += '<th>' + key_values[1] + '</th>'
    html += '<th>' + key_values[2] + '</th>'
    # Then we access the 1st element of dict_item key in dict_data
    html += '<th>' + dict_data[dict_item][0] + '</th>'
    # And then the 2nd 
    html += '<th>' + dict_data[dict_item][1] + '</th>'
    # Let's mark the end of the row before the next loop (if any)
    html += '</tr>'
# Do not forget to close the table too
html += '</table>'    
# Here's the final result    
print html
```